# How to assign a word(number) from a listbox to a textbox

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have an application in VB.Net that displays the results of a math operation to a listbox. For example I have the 1 + 1 = 2.
What I'm trying to do is to have the first 2 numbers (1 and 1) copied to 2 different textboxes when listbox item is selected.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My VB.Net is a bit rusty, but something like this should do it:

In the SelectedIndexChanged event put this:

```
'Make sure that we have a selected item before continuing
If listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
    Return
End If

'Get the text of the selected item
Dim selectedtext As String = listBox1.Items(listBox1.SelectedIndex).ToString()

'Split the item by the + and the = into an array of strings
Dim parts As String() = selectedtext.Split("+"C, "="C)

'If we have more than 2 parts
If parts.Length > 2 Then
    'Define a variable for each part
    Dim part1 As String = parts(0).Trim()
    Dim part2 As String = parts(1).Trim()

        'Make text boxes set to part1 and part2. part1 = 1, part2 = 1
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This code only works for the index 1. I have 10 records (0 to 9). All the others when selected nothing happens. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide more examples of the other ones? are they all just 2 numbers being added together and the result?

Comment: Sure. I actually have the textboxes set to 5 digits. My records looks like these: 12345 + 12345 , or 12345 - 12345 and so on. Hope this clarifies it...